# DataTable.Rows.Add(): Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, multithreading, datatable

I have a dataset which shared across different threads. But each DataTable is only used exclusively on a particular thread. Every now and then I get this error: `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

Here is my code:

```
DataTable dt = null;
lock (ds)
{
    dt = ds.Tables.Add("FeedbackSummary");
}

dt.Columns.Add("FeedbackId", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Question", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Total Ratings", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Total Votes", typeof(int));

List<Feedback> feedbacks = GetFeedbacks();
foreach (Feedback f in feedbacks)
{
    int id = f.FeedbackId;
    DataRow dr = dt.Select("FeedbackId=" + id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (dr == null)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["FeedbackId"] = id;
        dr["Question"] = f.Question;
        dr["Total Ratings"] = 0;
        dr["Total Votes"] = 0;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr); //error occurs here. dt.Rows.Count is 0
    }

    dr["Total Votes"] = (int)dr["Total Votes"] + f.TotalVotes;
    dr["Total Ratings"] = (int)dr["Total Ratings"] + f.TotalRating;
}
```

It occurs on `dt.Rows.Add` even though DataTable is not shared and no `foreach` is performed on DataTable's rows. To make the matter worse, it happens intermittently.

The complete errors (from exception's StackTrace):

```
at System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext()
at System.Data.ConstraintEnumerator.GetNext()
at System.Data.DataTable.CascadeAll(DataRow row, DataRowAction action)
at System.Data.DataTable.RaiseRowChanging(DataRowChangeEventArgs args, DataRow eRow, DataRowAction eAction, Boolean fireEvent)
at System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(DataRow row, Int32 proposedRecord, DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Boolean suppressEnsurePropertyChanged, Int32 position, Boolean fireEvent, Exception& deferredException)
at System.Data.DataTable.InsertRow(DataRow row, Int64 proposedID, Int32 pos, Boolean fireEvent)
at System.Data.DataRowCollection.Add(DataRow row)
at Website.GenerateFeedbackSummary(DataSet ds) in C:\Pro\Website\Website\Utils\Reports.Summary.cs:line 88
at Website.ReportUtils.<>c__DisplayClass80_0.<GenerateReportSummary>b__3() in C:\Pro\Website\Website\Utils\ReportUtil.cs:line 565
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Any idea?

Thanks...

Here is the code for GetFeedbacks()

```
using (EFOrderDB ef = DBProvider.Create())
{
    return DBProvider.GetRetryPolicy().ExecuteAction<List<Feedback>>(() =>
    {
        return (from rec in ef.Feedbacks.AsNoTracking()
                select rec).Take(20).ToList<Feedback>();
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be looping through your table's rows at any point, so I'm a bit confused by this exception. Are you sure the code is the complete context? Are you really creating a new table with new columns? If so, maybe something to do with the lock...

Comment: Could you try doing the exact same thing outside a multithreaded scenario? See what happens.

Comment: I suggest that you use an exclusive lock every time you are about to change the metadata of the `DataSet` (by adding tables, columns and constraints).

Comment: Your `dr` is not declared in the above snippet, so it must be declared elsewhere. You also do not provide info on what `GetFeedbacks` does. Is there any possible conflict with dr there perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, the dr is declared. I must have accidentally deleted it when formatting. It supposes to be `DataRow dr = dt.Select("FeedbackId=" + id).FirstOrDefault();`. I will update the code for GetFeedback()

Comment: @CodingYoshi, I think if it is outside multithreading, it works fine. The error is intermittent... I can guarantee that the ds.Tables.Add("FeedbackSummary"); is only called once.

Comment: Well I was hoping you'd do a quick test to confirm how it behaves outside multithreading. Saying "I think" is not a confirmation. Once we know that, we can then investigate.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, Just removed the multithreading and it worked! However, this is not 100% confirmation as it will also work in multithreading. The error occurs every now and then (extremely **rare**, but it does happen). I am now trying Theodor's suggestions by adding columns inside the lock.